# fixing cakephp .htaccess/mod_rewrite for shared hosting setups

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I'm trying to install cakePHP on a shared hosting setup.  After extracting the files to a location like **~/public_html/dev/cake** and visiting the appropriate URL (in this case **http://hostname/~username/dev/cake/**), I receive a 404 error:

---

Not Found

The requested URL /usr/home/username/public_html/dev/cake/app/webroot/ was not found on this server.

---

I suspect that the reason for this is that upon closer inspection, the absolute path to **~/public_html** is not in fact **/usr/home/username/public_html**, but rather **/usr/www/users/username/**.

Here's what I've been trying (but obviously it's not working):
(~/public_html/dev/cake/app/webroot/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase /usr/www/users/username/dev/cake/app/webroot/ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to change anything (the 404 message remains that same).  Thoughts?

Comment: It should be noted that this is 1.3 style. For 2.x the Rule has changed! It is now `index.php?/$1` (no url= part anymore) in case someone is trying to use it now with current versions of CakePHP.

Answer (score 13):

Shouldn't

```
RewriteBase /usr/www/users/username/dev/cake/app/webroot/
```

be

```
RewriteBase /~username/dev/cake/
```

[`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) cares about mapping real urls to virtual ones, and I think that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, RewriteBase refers to the logical/virtual URL, not to the filesystem location

Comment: you ended my quest of resolving this .htaccess problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying the wrong file. The .htaccess file you need to modify is found in /dev, you shouldn't be modifying the one in /dev/cake/app/webroot/.htaccess

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out that I THOUGHT the module was loaded because I saw the code but apparently it was not enabled!

To enable it in SSH (terminal) type the following command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

The command below shows all modules that are active, if it appears in the list then you have it installed.

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Make sure to restart the server with...

```
service apache2 restart
```

PhpCake should start working now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just extract the files to `/usr/www/users/username/`?

Comment: So I looked around and I _think_ that's where the files actually reside.

If I understand Pair (my host) correctly, there's a Home (/usr/home/username) and a Web directory (/usr/www/users/username), which is symlinked to /usr/home/username/public_html (aka ~/public_html).

Answer (score 1):

i think the .htaccess is reading that '~' and thinking you are refering to your home folder (which is something of a shortcut in linux).

fastest way to get your app running is to go to cake's config/core.php and disable use of rewrite (it tells u to uncomment some stuff and delete some .htaccess file). the other way is to edit your .htaccess and somehow tell it '~' is not refering to home directory. maybe a simple \ will work.

Comment: Disabling rewrite definitely works, thanks.  I think I'll just run with that for now.

Comment: That's probably not the problem: I have a similar setup on my box (localhost/~user/cake) and it works alright.
Try enabling the rewrite log: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog . If your host didn't disable the directive, it could help you see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am hosting on pair and I was able to get the rewrite rules to work but, I am having problems with the HTML->link getting the sort parameters for all links in the pages.  Same code runs fine on my local machine running window but on pair sorting or too many query parameters (Edit or Update pages) causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to give the DOCUMENT_ROOT path in the following files.  Please refer to phpinfo() of your server to get correct DOCUMENT_ROOT path.  It should be something like `var/www/html/`.

1. .htaccess in the root **/** directory (Outside the app,cake,vendors directories)

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ ) DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. .htaccess inside the **/app** directory

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$    DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/webroot/$1    [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. .htaccess inside the **/app/webroot** directory

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

It worked for me.

Comment: how to find tht in godaddy?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with 'advanced installation' from the official CakePHP Cockbook. After couple of hours I managed to get it working.

OS: Mac OS X

Cake core directory: **/usr/lib/cake** 
My application app directory: **/Users/myuser/dev/myapp** 
My application webroot directory: **/Users/myuser/Sites/myapp**

Modification of **/Users/myuser/Sites/myapp/index.php**

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'myuser'.DS.'dev');
}
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', 'myapp');
}
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'usr'.DS.'lib');
}
```

Modification of **/Users/myuser/Sites/myapp/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /~myuser/myapp/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

As for **/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/.htaccess** - this file is not needed in this configuration so I deleted it. The most tricky part with this configuration is enabling mod_rewrite in Apache. On Mac editing **/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** seems to be pointless (for this task). Additional Apache configuration file is created for each user.

Modification of **/private/etc/apache2/users/myuser.conf**

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

By default AllowOverride is set to None, so mod_rewrite will not work in this configuration.

After this changes **http://localhost/~myuser/myapp** works properly.

PS. Quick permission fix for tmp directory.

```
sudo chgrp -R www /Users/myuser/dev/myapp/tmp
sudo chmod -R g+w /Users/myuser/dev/myapp/tmp
```