# installing cakephp in subdirectory ; joomla in the root

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, joomla

I'm having a problem with my CakePHP installation.

i need installing cakephp in subdirectory and joomla in the root .

for example : 127.0.0.1/joomla/estate

1)127.0.0.1/joomla/estate/.htaccess :

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /estate/
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

1)127.0.0.1/joomla/estate/app/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /estate/app/
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

1)127.0.0.1/joomla/estate/app/webroot/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /estate/app/webroot/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

only view internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

[fixing cakephp .htaccess/mod_rewrite for shared hosting setups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952999/fixing-cakephp-htaccess-mod-rewrite-for-shared-hosting-setups)
(This post helped me undestand usage of RewriteBase)

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html (Documentation for url rewriting in cake)

Answer (score 0):

I only thought you needed to set RewriteBase in the .htaccess in your installation-root ( /estate). If you keep getting 500-errors, try to disable the .htaccess-files one after another to see which one is failing. Check that there are no permission-errors on the htaccess-files (444 should be good) or other files, some servers will give you 500-errors for this as well.

There might be useful information in the server logs, if you have access to these.